# How to mount /usr in CoreOS from NFS?

Tags: coreos, coreos-ignition

We are working on diskless (not really diskless, but with readonly disks) stations. So we found a way to store all havy stuff on remote disk. Is there any way to mount /usr from NFS partition?

Answer (score 0):

NFS for /usr is not needed when [the CoreOS PXE boot method](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-with-pxe.html) downloads the entire squashfs into RAM. Uncompressed it is maybe 0.7 GB, relatively small.

Add [systemd mount units](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/mounting-storage.html) for NFS or whatever other mounts you like.